# Selecting columns that are not all null

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-null

So I have a query that looks like this -

```
select 
case when @subType = 1 or @subType = 2 then id end as Id,
case when  @subType = 3 then name end as name
case when @subType = 3 or @subType = 2 then address end as address
from 
table
```

So the issue I have is, that if @subType is 3, then the column named ID will all be null. I then don't want to return this entire column. Conversely to that, if @subType is 2, then name would all be null so I don't want that entire column.

Comment: The result set of a `SELECT` statement must have a constant shape, determined at compile time. If you want to return different *columns*, depending on `@subType`, you must use multiple statements and use `IF` .. `ELSE` to choose between them. This will make processing the result potentially more difficult, though, since now your client would not be able to count on all columns being present.

Comment: Why do you want such a query in the first place? It will return different data types in each case, which means the *client* will have to either treat all of them as text, object, dynamic or a weakly typed value, depending on the language

Comment: BTW this query won't return NULLs. If `subtype` is 3, you'll get `name` *only*. Neither `Address` nor `ID` will be returned.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it will return null for the id when subtype is 3.

Comment: `[address]` would return is the value of `@subtype` is `3`, @PanagiotisKanavos, the `CASE` expression is `case when @subType = 3 or @subType = 2 then address end as address`

Comment: @Larnu (facepalm). And syntax error on all columns except the first

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there are 3 CASE statements for each row.

Comment: @forpas and missing commas at the end of each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you could do this would be with dynamic SQL (as Gordon mentions). Provided this is a query, and not a function, view, then you could do this:

```
DECLARE @subType tinyint = 3;

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' +
           STUFF(CASE WHEN @subType IN (1,2) THEN N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + N'       id' ELSE N'' END + 
                 CASE WHEN @subType = 3 THEN N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + N'       [name]' ELSE N'' END + 
                 CASE WHEN @subType IN (3,2) THEN N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + N'       [address]' ELSE N'' END, 1, 10,N'') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM YourTable;';

PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging best friend.
--EXEC sp_executesql @SQL; --Uncomment to run the statement
```

But, if the query is coming from a presentation layer, then really that should be handling what columns are being displayed, not SQL Server

If you're passing parameters to the `WHERE` of your query as well, ensure that you parametrise the call to `sp_executesql`; *do not* inject the parameter values into the dynamic statement.

Comment: This is exactly what im after. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns, with the names and types defined in the `SELECT`.  It cannot have a variable number of columns.

In order to do what you want, you would need to use dynamic SQL.  I'm not sure if that works in your context.  For instance, dynamic SQL is not supported in SQL Server user-defined functions.

Comment: user can use dual table then it can be created in SQL server!!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh what would that do? `dual` is just a numbers table. It doesn't affect nulls