# Passing in multiple Id's to return columns on case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, dynamic-sql

I am using some dynamic SQL to return some columns based on a subscription type. The issue I have got is multiple subscription types. Whilst I can competently handle 1 subscription type. I can't work out how to handle 2 subscription types. I have 8 different types in total.

For example:

```
DECLARE @subType tinyint = 2

DECLARE @Id varchar(4) = 'U01'
DECLARE @SQLProjectDetails nvarchar(MAX)

SET @SQLProjectDetails = N'SELECT ' +
       STUFF(
            -- General Information 

            CASE WHEN @subType IN (1,2,3,4) THEN N',' + NCHAR(13) + 
                 NCHAR(10) + N'        wf1.Id' ELSE N'' END + 
            CASE WHEN @subType IN (1,2) THEN N',' + NCHAR(13) + 
                 NCHAR(10) + N'        wf1.Name' ELSE N'' END + 
            CASE WHEN @subType IN (5,6,8) THEN N',' + NCHAR(13) + 
                 NCHAR(10) + N'       wf1.OtherNames' ELSE N'' END +
            CASE WHEN @subType IN (1,2) THEN N',' + NCHAR(13) + 
                 NCHAR(10) + N'        wf1.CountryName' ELSE N'' END +
             , 1, 10,N'') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
            N'FROM Table wf1where (wf1.Id= @p)';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLProjectDetails,  N'@p varchar(4)', @p = @Id;
```

But what If I they have a subscription type of 2 and 5?

So the othernames column would be returned as well? The main issue that I have is the 8 different subscription types. Whilst I Could try and cover every possible eventuality, I would much prefer to do this dynamically (mainly because there is 40000 odd different variations).

Comment: This question is hard to answer; it doesn't (to me) clearly explain what you're trying to do, or why what you have doesn't meet your need

Comment: Surely you'd be better off just writing a normal query and returning a fixed column list and NULL for irrelevant columns depending on the subscription?

Comment: ps; you're making an SQL string that you'll eventually execute dynamically - the parser doesn't care a hoot about newlines so you can drop all those `NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)` calls - theyre just adding clutter to what you're developing, and if you'd use the `CONCAT` command you could drop all the `ELSE` too because CONCAT doesn't null the whole string upon encountering a NULL (concat treats null like empty string), viz: `CONCAT(CASE WHEN blah THEN blah END, CASE WHEN blah2 THEN blah2 end, …)`

Comment: @CaiusJard no it's a good idea to have them (the line breaks). Yes, the parser doesn't care, but neither does it about non-dynamic SQL. The reason they are there is to aid in debugging the SQL in the event it doesn't work. You should format your dynamic SQL, just like you format your non-dynamic SQL. That comment above is bad advice. Imagine trying to debug a huge dynamic statement that is one huge line of 3,000 characters, and another that has lots of line breaks, indentation, etc. I know which one I'd like to debug.

Comment: I am returning certain columns based on a subscription type. The actual query is really big and this is just a snippet. I dont want or need the columns to return if they are not included in a subscription type. And I actually print the sql statement for debugging, those extra lines are super helpful!

Comment: @Larnu then just put newlines in strings (press ' key, press return key, press ' key - unlike languages like c#, sql permits newlines to appear in strings/doesn't demand that strings start and end on the same line), you don't need to laboriously write Char(13)+Char(10)

Comment: Those are actually harder to format. Also that code is from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55727103/3484879) I gave them. :) I have good reasons for the that, but the article i wrote isn't published yet. I'll be happy to share with you once it is (hopefully soon).

Comment: @samsmith maybe, but the more sensible approach would be to avoid the dynamic SQL entirely.. No matter how you format it, this query is a mess, that someone is going to have to maintain, and could be done entirely differently..

Comment: Its really not a mess. It does a perfect job and I shall be the one maintaining it. It's heavily commented!

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to have a lookup table, that defines what columns are displayed for a specific subscription type instead? You may well need to create 3 tables; one with the subscription details, another with all the columns, and then a joining table, for the many to many relationship.

Comment: Heh, OK. If I came across it in prod code I had to maintain, I'd take it out - it's already so unwieldy an approach you're having to ask on SO for help to manage it (that should be a clue as to whether it's worth considering other options) :)

Comment: @larnu "which columns to display" - that's the job of the end reporting system, not the DB

Comment: Surely thats going to have the same issue, of 40000 different variations?

Comment: I do appreciate your advise though Caius!

Comment: In terms of dynamic SQL, @CaiusJard this is quite simple really. And I don't disagree that the display layer should be making the decision here (I stated that in my previous answer linked above).

Comment: Yes, it will @samsmith, but you won't need to code them all. You'll have a "look up table", and the dynamic SQL will be quite small; making it far more maintable than some 10,000 or so `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Could you potentially post an example? So I'd have column names in a lookup table?

Comment: @samsmith pps; a dyn sql like: `CONCAT(CASE WHEN blah then 'somecolumn,--!' END, …)` can be exec'd, or it can be `PRINT(REPLACE(sql, '--!', CHAR(10)))`'d for debugging...

Comment: You'll likely have 3 tables, as I said, One with your subscription details. one with the column names, and then a joining table, which says which columns are displayed for which subscription; like i explained above.

Comment: but am I still not going to end up with 40000 different variations, which is going to take me forever, with the amount of columns I have?? Due to multiple subscription types?

Comment: How else are you going to determine which columns to display without defining it then? Magic? :D

Comment: @sam no, you don't have that much work to. Just because there are 40,000 combinations doesn't mean you list every one; you need only specify the number of subtypes for each column.. If you're outputting 20 columns and each column only relates to 3 subtypes, then you have to code 60 instructions (3x20), but there are 3486784401 combinations (3^20)

Comment: But I already do that within my case statements? Surely I must be able to easily pass in 2 subTypes? Or would it be a case of iterating through in my c# and removing the duplicate columns?

Comment: You should be doing this in your C# anyway

Comment: How many subtypes are there in total? How many subtypes can each WF1 entity (for a given unique ID 1234 in table WF1, what is the maximum number of subtypes it has)?

Answer (score 0):

If you had a ColLookup table like this:

```
SubType, ColumnName
1,wf1.Id
2,wf1.Id
3,wf1.Id
4,wf1.Id
1,wf1.Name
2,wf1.Name
5,wf1.OtherNames
6,wf1.OtherNames
8,wf1.OtherNames
1,wf1.CountryName
2,wf1.CountryName
```

Then an SQL like this will give you the column names you should pull:

```
SELECT 
  STRING_AGG(l.ColumnName, ',') as ColList
FROM
  otherTable o
  INNER JOIN
  ColLookup l on o.subtype = l.subtype
WHERE
  o.id = 1234
```

If o.id 1234's subtype was 1, this SQL would return

```
'wf1.Id,1,wf1.Name,wf1.CountryName'
```

If o.id X's subtype was 3, this SQL would return

```
'wf1.Id'
```

Making it a full SQL could be something like:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('SELECT ', STRING_AGG(l.ColumnName, ','), ' FROM blah')  as sq
FROM
  otherTable o
  INNER JOIN
  ColLookup l on o.subtype = l.subtype
WHERE
  o.id = 1234
```

You could assign that to a variable and EXEC it

If your SQLS is pre-2017 and doesn't have STRING_AGG use a similar method of concatenating multiple rows into a single string, like STUFF/FOR XML PATH. If there is a defined order required, add an order column to the lookup table (STRING_AGG has WITHIN GROUP ORDER BY option, I'm sure other methods also have options to change the order of the concatted string)

Genuinely though, I'd do this in the C#. I'd run the main query that selects everything and then I'd run:

```
SELECT ColName FROM ColLookup WHERE SubType in (1,5)
```

I'd put it into a dictionary/hashset (this using linq pseudocode, but however you want):

```
//this is a union - anything 1 can see or 5 can see
var dict = dbcontext.Wf1Table.Where(r => r == 1 || r == 5).Distinct().ToDictionary(r => r.ColumnName, r => r.ColumnName)

//this is an intersect - anything common to 1 and 5 only
var dict = dbcontext.Wf1Table.Where(r => r == 1).Intersect(dbcontext.Wf1Table.Where(r => r == 5)).ToDictionary(r => r.ColumnName, r => r.ColumnName)

//this is if you downloaded the columns into a datatable
//SELECT DISTINCT colname FROM t WHERE subtype IN (1,5) --union
//SELECT colname FROM t WHERE subtype IN (1,5) GROUP BY colname HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 --intersection
var dict = new Dictionary(string, string);
foreach(var ro in colnamedatatable)
  dict[ro.ColName] = null;
```

And I'd pull my main query into a datatable and remove the columns unwanted:

```
for(int c = datatable.Columns.Length -1; c >= 0; c--) //gobackwards
  if(!dict.ContainsKey(datatable.Columns[c].ColumnName))
    datatable.Columns.RemoveAt(c);
```

If you want to persist in doing this in SQL, this will give an intersect:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('SELECT ', STRING_AGG(l.ColumnName, ','), ' FROM blah')  as sq
FROM
  otherTable o
  INNER JOIN
  ColLookup l on o.subtype = l.subtype
WHERE
  o.id = @id
GROUP BY
  l.ColumnName
HAVING COUNT(*) = @count_of_subtypes_for_that_id
```

Something needs to know how many subtypes there are for a given ID; the DB knows but it's hard to guide you on this because you haven't said how the data is stored. If it's properly (multiple ID records/middleman table) then this query works out. If it's "comma separated list" then (ugh) it needs parsing out to two rows

Comment: But what if they have a subscription type of 1 and 3? So if they could see wf1.Id with  a sub type of 1...but couldnt see wf1.name with sub type 1. yet they could see wf1.name with sub type 3?

Comment: Eh? your original SQL says "if subtype is 1 output the id ... and … if subtype is 1 output the name column". Now you're telling me subtype 1 *doesn't* output the name column?

Comment: If your ID 1234 can have a subtype of 1 and a subtype of 3, you're really causing yourself a problem with the data modelling, but it's still doable, just make sure you use the DISTINCT output from the lookup table

Comment: I feel i've explained this really poorly. :( 

Ok, so End user - can have multiple subscription types. The query above can handle 1 subscription type. But not multiple types.

Comment: Why can't it handle multiple types? Do you think SQLServer will only join once and then give up?

Comment: (I get the feeling this is the part where you say "oh, because my SubType column is a comma separated list of all the subtypes. There might be 5000 for a single subscriber")

Comment: and me changing the name column was just an example. In my original query  If the end user has a sub type of just '1'. Then it would return - Id, Name and CountryName. But not otherName. If they had a subtype of just 5 - then it only returns Othernames. BUT what if they have a sub type of 1 AND 5.

Comment: No, they can only have 2 subscription types Maximum.

Comment: *"what if they have a sub type of 1 AND 5"* I don't know! You're designing this system, not me.. What is the rule? Should it only show the intersection of columns? The union? (intersec = only columns common to both 1 and 5, union = the distinct list of columns from 1 appended to 5)

Comment: Oh sorry, im really bad at this. It should only show columns that 1 and 5 should be able to see.

Comment: And yes, there is no reason why It couldn't check for subtype 1, and then check for subtype 5 and then append the distinct columsn on the end.

Comment: Yeah, really confused now!

Comment: (Confused because you said *"only show columns that 1 and 5 should be able to see"* which to me means "intersection", and then you said *"check for subtype 1, and then check for subtype 5 and then append the distinct columsn on the end"* which to me means "union". May I suggest you read up on UNION vs INTERSECTION, and start using one of those words to describe what you want. StackOverflow is a place for precise language, because the computers we work with demand precise instruction.. You'll get more out of us if you can explain clearly what you want